# Hide the default resizegrip in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, resizegrip

Is it possible to hide the default resize grip in wpf, I have a custom window without handles on the sides and are currently using:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="100" Width="200" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    <Grid></Grid>
</Window>
```

I know it's possible to just change `ResizeMode="CanResize"` but this is the only way to resize the window that I can think of.

Comment: I don't get it - what's wrong with your proposed solution of using CanResize. I believe the only difference between that and CanResizeWithGrip is the grip.

Comment: I do not use a window border which removes the CanResize handles, but I managed to just create a class with eight rectangles as parameters to use as handles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can take out the default resize grip from the Window. You need to override the WindowTemplate. Here is how you would do in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None" 
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Window.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border>

            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Template>
</Window>
```

Within the "Border" will go everything that you need to display in the Window (e.g. a TextBox). Then if you want your custom ResizeGrip you can define that as well. Hope this helps.